# MVC: AngularJS posted data is null in the cotroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have that code in the angularJS factory:

```
   myFactory.addNC = function (n) {
        return $http.post('/api/addNC/', { c: n }).then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
```

MVC ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
public void addNC([FromUri]string c = null)
{
   ...
}
```

but 'c' param is null, why ? I see in FireBug that the value is being posted.

Also, if I declare the param like `public void addNewCat([FromUri]string c)` I get the 404 error - why ?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `[FromBody]` for a POST?

Comment: then I get the 500 error: An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Optional parameter 'c' is not supported by 'FormatterParameterBinding'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Oh it's just a string. Try removing the attribute altogether

Comment: still nothing, I get the null value

Comment: What does your routing rule look like and secondly, can you hit it from your browser?

Comment: I use the default WebApi routing config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     "api",
     "api/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "api", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );. And yes, if I add the [HttpGet] attribute I can access to that action via browser address bar

Comment: @Tony - if you are using the default route then the action you are invoking in your post "addNC" is not the actual name of the action. Your action name is "addNewCat" - so the url needs to be /api/addNewCat. If you want to have the name of your route use addNC, then use attribute routing.

Comment: oh, my mistake, of course the controller's action name is the same as in the JS code

Comment: If you are looking for it to work that way you will need to change the content type header to "x-www-form-urlencoded" and also modify your data to be { "c": n }. You can change the content type in the following way $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Comment: still nothing, I did it like you said and Gjohn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65434/discussion-between-gjohn-and-tony).

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are expecting is for angular js $http.post to behave like jQuery.ajax(). This isn't the case because jquery.ajax transmits with contentType=x-www-form-urlencoded while angular always transmits with contentType=application/json. I would look at your API and check if you can transmit a request with content type json. There are add-on's to browsers that you can use to facilitate this. You can also work around this by ensuring Angular's $http.post behave like the jquery.ajax call by extending it. See the following [link](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/) for details